# Why does gfortran give segfault error when trying to replace file?

Tags: windows, gdb, fortran, gfortran

```
program test
  implicit none

  open(100, file="a.dat", status="replace")

end program test
```

When I try to run this program, it runs fine the first time when the file has not been created. But an attempt to run the program again (when the file a.dat exists and should be replaced) gives segfault error. Here is what I found using gdb.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff95deb1150 in strcmp () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
```

I am using *GNU Fortran (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.1.0* with target as *Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32*. I didn't use any extra compiler flags except -g.

Also since gdb mentions Windows system files, here is which OS I use - Windows 8.1

Comment: Just ran the exact same code with gfortran 4.6.3 and ifort 14.0.2 on my linux machine and your code gave me no errors

Comment: Yes. Until gfortran 4.9.2, this runs fine. I updated my compiler to gfortran 5.1 and encountered this error. Also, remember that this error only shows when the file has to be replaced (i.e. not on first run).

Comment: This is obviously some problem with your compiler installation or the compiler itself. Contact whoever prepared the distribution.

Comment: Do you get the problem running on a 32-bit cmd prompt or 64-bit cmd prompt or are you using bash

Comment: This compiles & runs fine with gfortran 5.1 on Linux.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Which gfortran 5.1 build are you using? I got from [mingw-w64 sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/). It says *gcc version 5.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)*. Also, first run is always fine. Did you try to run again without deleting a.dat?

Comment: @cup I use 32 bit cmd.

Comment: I just used [equation.com](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran) 5.1.0 64-bit build, and I am getting the same error.

Comment: @cup I also used 64 bit cmd and got the same error.

Comment: File a bug with mingw